# sorting array containing dates using usort not working

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, date

I have an array with d-m-y values that i need to sort, but my function isnt properly working, any ideas on how can i fix it?

each array element is contained in the following format: "TB" + dd + mm + yy + "12" (sorry not my fault xD), so first i need to remove the extra strings and then reorder the date to a mmddyy format to convert it using mktime

```
usort($periodos, 'date_compare');

function date_compare($a, $b) {
    // Reomves "TB" at the beginning and "12" at the end
    $t1 = substr($a, 2, -2);
    $t2 = substr($b, 2, -2);

    $t1 = mktime(0, 0, 0, substr($t1, 4, 2), substr($t1, 2, 2), substr($t1, 6, 2));
    $t2 = mktime(0, 0, 0, substr($t2, 4, 2), substr($t2, 2, 2), substr($t2, 6, 2));

    return $t1 - $t2;
}
```

but some days are off... and i dont understand what can be failing, the output is:

array(151) {
  [0]=>
  string(10) "TB07010012"
  [1]=>
  string(10) "TB23040012"
  [2]=>
  string(10) "TB26050012"
  [3]=>
  string(10) "TB28050012"
  [4]=>
  string(10) "TB21050012"
  [5]=>
  string(10) "TB07050012"
  [6]=>
  string(10) "TB25060012"
  [7]=>
  string(10) "TB16070012"
  [8]=>
  string(10) "TB24090012"
  [9]=>
  string(10) "TB31121312"
  [10]=>
  string(10) "TB09011412"
  [11]=>
  string(10) "TB16011412"
  [12]=>
  string(10) "TB30011412"
  [13]=>
  string(10) "TB23011412"
  [14]=>
  string(10) "TB06021412"
  .....
  .....

and as you can see everything seems ok until the element 12 (300114 -> jan 30 2014) that should be after element 13 (230114 -> 23 jan 2014), there are other similar mistakes but the array is 151 elements long so i dont think is necesary to post it all..

Thanks for your help

Comment: Try strcmp($t1, $t2) instead of $t1 - $t2

Comment: Nope... it didnt worked, the error stays there

Comment: You can try to rewrite the array using timestamps and recreate the date to the right format on output.

Comment: $t1 and $t2 are integers. I meant to compare the dates as strings. Instead of mktime, try reformating dates to yyyy-mm-dd and then use strcmp()

Comment: It didnt worked either... but after making your suggestion i noticed that my substr functions are wrong... it should be $t1 = mktime(0, 0, 0, substr($t1, 2, 2), substr($t1, 0, 2), substr($t1, 4, 2)), thanks for your help!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some suggestions i noticed that my substr indexes are wrong... im leaving the correct function here in case someone has the same problem...

```
function date_compare($a, $b) {
    // Reomves "TB" at the beginning and "12" at the end
    $t1 = substr($a, 2, -2);
    $t2 = substr($b, 2, -2);

    $t1 = mktime(0, 0, 0, substr($t1, 2, 2), substr($t1, 0, 2), substr($t1, 4, 2));
    $t2 = mktime(0, 0, 0, substr($t2, 2, 2), substr($t2, 0, 2), substr($t2, 4, 2));

    return $t1 - $t2;
}
```

Comment: If you're happy this is the correct answer to your question, you should accept it.